# Cannot install python-pip on Kali Linux

Tags: python, kali-linux

OK so I am a total noob and I just installed Kali Linux. I am trying to install python-pip by command

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

and I am getting this output

```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

I've checked my source **/ect/apt/sources.list** and it says

> deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib

I've run apt-get updates several times too and it's not helping. Please help.

Comment: what is the output when you just type ```python```

Comment: It says `python 2.7.18rc1 (default date and time)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At-First Open Your `sources.list` File With any Editor.

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add these Lines.

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib 
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Not Update and Upgrade Your Kali Linux Using These Commands.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

and then Install `pip` using this command

```
apt-get install python-pip   #For Python2
apt-get install python3-pip  #For Python3
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a high chance python-pip is not available, because 'python' is python2, and python2 is finally dead. Try to install `python3-pip`.

There is a convention that python without '3' is python2, and it's gonna last like that, I think, forever, due to compatibility reasons.

Comment: I've already installed Python3-pip and it is the latest version. The problem is I am installing nuriyadin/InstaBurst and during the `sudo ./install.sh` it keeps saying `Unable to locate python-pip` `pip command not found` and some other packages by `glob 'php7.0-cgi' and regex 'php7.0-cgi' `and the installation fails.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /
cd etc/apt/
sudo nano sources.list
```

After opening the editor paste the following line if not present.

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

run the following command

```
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python-pip
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `apt-get install python3-pip`. This will install `pip3` on your machine.

Comment: I've already installed Python3-pip and it is the latest version. The problem is I am installing nuriyadin/InstaBurst and during the `sudo ./install.sh` it keeps saying `Unable to locate python-pip` `pip command not found` and some other packages by `glob 'php7.0-cgi' and regex 'php7.0-cgi' `and the installation fails.

Comment: At minimum you may try to cheat them (alias pip=pip3), but if they are insisting on using python2, than they use unsupported python version. If you want, you can install python and pip by yourself (manual compilation, a lot of grind and hard work). Basically, python2 is DEAD, and no reasonable amount of efforts would revive it. (Or you can boot VM with old distro and use it - f.e. Ubuntu 18.04 would support python for few more years).

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `sudo apt install python3-pip` and didn't work. So I tried again with `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and it worked fine. I'm using Kali Linux too.
[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the repositories to `sources.list`

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And add

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Save and run

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade 
apt-get install python-pip #or python3-pip
```

And type

```
pip --version #or pip3
```

To more info [click here](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/) and [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#installing-pip)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to install pip for python 2.7:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Now you have:

```
$ pip --version    
pip 20.3.4 from /home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

$ pip3 --version
pip 21.0.1 from /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Comment: That link was broken.  So I google dorked 'site:bootstrap.pypa.io get-pip.py' and found a good url: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py.  That allows me to do `python -m pip [command]` but pip --version still says 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt update       
sudo apt install python3   
sudo apt install python3-pip  
python3 -m pip install -r
```

This video helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EHUGDnvqoA

Answer (score 0):

**Try following commands:**

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

**Hope it will help u!**

Answer (score 0):

Make your source.list like this

```
nano /etc/apt/source.list

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib deb-src
http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Update Your kali

```
sudo apt-get update && upgrade
```

Now install python-pip

```
apt-get install python-pip or apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: This looks basically the same as a number of other answers. You should probably clarify what the differences are and why they're different, or you should delete it since it's superfluous

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If already python 2.7 version is installed , first remove that in cmd terminal

Type >> *sudo apt purge -y python2-minimal*

then install python latest version

Type >> *sudo apt install -y python3-pip*

python is installed!

Answer (score 0):

Not found pip try this command
1: sudo apt install python3-pip
2: pip3 install -r requirements.txt
3: /usr/local/bin/python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue that i was using python2 not python3 you may check your python version you have

Answer (score 0):

None of these seemed to work for me as it had some unmet dependencies. This is what fixed it for me (commands in the terminal).

```
sudo apt-get update

apt-get install libjs-mathjax fonts-mathjax

sudo apt-get intall python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

you can install pip using the get-pip.py script provided by the Python Packaging Authority.

**get-pip.py**

This is a Python script that uses some bootstrapping logic to install pip.

1-Download the script, from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py.
by typing the command:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

2-Open a terminal/command prompt, cd to the folder containing the get-pip.py file and run:

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

Make sure to use python3 instead of python to install pip for Python 3.

3-After the installation is complete, verify pip by running the following command:

```
pip3 --version
```

Answer (score -1):

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade

This works

Answer (score -2):

**Try this :**

sudo apt update

sudo apt install python3

sudo apt install python3-pip

python3 -m pip install -r

Comment: Downvoted because it's the same as another answer - it adds nothing

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue, here is the command that helped me:

`sudo apt install python-pip`

This command will install pip to your system.